# stopping a background execution before it gets executed

Tags: ios, multithreading, objective-c-blocks, background-process

I have written a background processing logic using dispatch_async as follows:

```
- (IBAction)textFieldChanged:(id)sender {
dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
     NSArray *tempArray = [myClass getSuggestionArray]; //getSuggestionArray returns an array of objects from a database
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(initSuggestionArray:) withObject:tempArray waitUntilDone:YES];
    });
}
```

As you can see, this method gets called everytime user edits the textfield (as soon as user types a letter).
kBgQueue is defined as:

```
#define kBgQueue dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)
```

What I want is some method, some logic so that whenever user edits the field I can check whether there is already a queued task in this kBgQueue or not and if it is, then I want to stop the execution of that queued job before starting the next block.(want to remove the previous one) I am using this so that the UI of the application doesn't look like it hanged, if user types 3-4 characters quickly (because result is coming too late from my database)

Answer (score 1):

You could use an NSOperationQueue instead of your GCD queue and add operations like this:

```
[queue addOperationWithBlock:^{
    NSArray *tempArray = [myClass getSuggestionArray];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self initSuggestionArray:tempArray];
    });
}];
```

Then you can cancel all your operations with

```
[queue cancelAllOperations];
```

If you need finer grained control you could subclass NSOperation and add some checks to see if the operation has been cancelled.

Comment: Hey tim, I think the operations are not getting cancelled because initSuggestionArrayMethod is getting called every time, event after cancelling the operation. The gdb is showing logs as:
    void _WebThreadLockFromAnyThread(bool), 0x7a9cf60: Obtaining the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. UIKit should not be called from a secondary thread.

Comment: You could also use an NSBlockOperation and check if has been cancelled before calling initSuggestionArray, you can find an example here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8113232/381870